# ValueError: Missing scheme in request url

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

When I run the following code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    search_url = ''

    def start_requests(self):
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.search_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

test_spider = QuotesSpider()
test_spider.search_url='http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'

process.crawl(test_spider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

I get the following error:

```
2019-06-10 08:33:01 [scrapy.core.engine] ERROR: Error while obtaining start requ
ests
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\core\engine.py", line 127, in _next
_request
    request = next(slot.start_requests)
  File "quotes_spider.py", line 10, in start_requests
    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.search_url, callback=self.parse)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 25,
 in __init__
    self._set_url(url)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\scrapy\http\request\__init__.py", line 62,
 in _set_url
    raise ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:
2019-06-10 08:33:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2019-06-10 08:33:01 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 10, 12, 33, 1, 539000),
 'log_count/ERROR': 1,
 'log_count/INFO': 9,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2019, 6, 10, 12, 33, 1, 534000)}
2019-06-10 08:33:01 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

It seems like when this line is executed:

```
yield scrapy.Request(url=self.search_url, callback=self.parse)
```

self.search_url seems to be an empty variable, even though I have explicitly set its value to something before calling the function. I cannot seem to figure out why that is.

Comment: `scrapy.spiders.Spider` [doesn't seem to](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/master/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py) have the `search_url` attribute at all.

Comment: Sorry, but my knowledge in python and programming in general is lacking. When I use test_spider.search_url within the error line it works, but how come self.search_url does not work?

Comment: printing `self.search_url` in `start_requests` works perfectly

Comment: @Gibson, the original `scrapy.spiders.Spider` is implemented [like this](https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/29bbbaa4dd3a985c594c03110ac0710f57f413d0/scrapy/spiders/__init__.py#L69). I think you should just set `test_spider.start_urls = ['your_url']`, as [the documentation suggests](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy-spider).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Empty variable within instance of a class, despite specifically setting it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56526926/empty-variable-within-instance-of-a-class-despite-specifically-setting-it)

Answer (score 1):

This way it works for me:

```
process.crawl(test_spider, search_url="http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/")
```