# Empty variable within instance of a class, despite specifically setting it

Tags: python, python-2.7, scrapy

When I run the following code:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "quotes"
    search_url = ''

    def start_requests(self):
        print ('self.search_url is currently: ' + self.search_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.search_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

test_spider = QuotesSpider()
test_spider.search_url='http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'

process.crawl(test_spider)
process.start() # the script will block here until the crawling is finished
```

I get the following error:

```
self.search_url is currently:
...
   ValueError('Missing scheme in request url: %s' % self._url)
ValueError: Missing scheme in request url:
...
```

It seems that within the function start_requests, self.search_url seems to be an empty variable, even though I have explicitly set its value to something before calling the function. I cannot seem to figure out why that is.

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to declare `search_url` as an instance attribute?  You could just pass it to the class?

Answer (score 1):

The neatest way to do this, would be to use the constructor `__init__()`, but an easier(maybe just faster for what you want) is to move the definition of `start_url` inside the class. For example:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess

class QuotesSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = "quotes"
    search_url = 'http://quotes.toscrape.com/page/1/'

    def start_requests(self):
        print ('search_url is currently: ' + self.search_url)
        yield scrapy.Request(url=self.search_url, callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        page = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        filename = 'quotes-%s.html' % page
        with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)
        self.log('Saved file %s' % filename)

process = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1)'
})

test_spider = QuotesSpider()

process.crawl(test_spider)
process.start()
```